# Applying JQuery Mobile's style to function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, d3.js

I have a D3 function that creates list items on a page. I want them to be styled by JQuery UI mobile, but when I call the function multiple ways they are never styled.

D3/JS:

```
var sampdata = [{itemname: "Placeholder0", numvalue: "$000,000"},
    {itemname: "Placeholder1", numvalue: "$543,600"},
    {itemname: "Placeholder2", numvalue: "$9,200"},
    {itemname: "Placeholder3", numvalue: "$5,100"}];

setupgui: function()
    {
        d3.select("#SampcoISrevenues").selectAll("li")
                .data(sampdata)
                .enter()
                .append("li")
                .text(function (d){return d.itemname;})
                .append("span")
                .attr("class", "right")
                .text(function (d){return d.numvalue;});
    }
```

Where this function picks out the part of the screen reserved, and then adds list items from "sampdata". 
HTML:

```
<body onload="Samplegui.setupgui()"> 
        <div data-role="content">
             <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" id="SampcoISrevenues">
             </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

I reference both the D3 library, my index.js, and JQuery (JQmobile.css/.js, JQ.js) in this order:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/index.css">
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/yourdata.js"></script>
```

Although the D3 function is run right away, JQuery mobile does not style it. I would like it to style it as it works really well for mobile.

Comment: It may be an issue of the jquery files not having loaded before d3 runs. is the ul taking the jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery's .ready() to run the function:

`$(document).ready(Samplegui.setupgui());`

Which is what I tried, but the problem was that I was running the D3 function before the actual HTML code was loaded, so D3 could not find the proper ids/tags. Sticking

```
   `<script>
        $(document).ready(Samplegui.setupgui());
    </script>`
```

at the bottom of the page solved it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**jQuery Mobile Docs for List Views**](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html):

> **Updating lists**
>
> If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added.

Try calling `$('#SampcoISrevenues').listview('refresh')` after you update the list in your d3 code.